# Кнопка очистки всех полей формы

Tags: javascript, формы

Есть обычная форма. Значения сохраняются в сессии и не удаётся её очистить при помощи стандартного `<input type="reset" />`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи javascript очистить всю форму?

Вот эта кнопка, очищает только поле «txt».

```
<input type="button" value="Очистить" onclick="this.form.elements[\'txt\'].value=\'\'" />
```

Comment: Что значит «сохраняются в сессии»? Если обычный reset не работает, значит нужно больше подробностей, что это за странная форма такая и как она работает

Answer (score 1):

У объекта формы вызвать метод reset
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

```html
<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset()" value="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Вот так: `<input type="button" value="Очистить всё" onclick="document.getElementById(\'artform\').reset();" />` к сожалению, почему-то не работает. Может быть, я ошибся в синтаксисе?

Comment: а зачем вы экранируете одинарные кавычки внутри двойных? Если у вас на странице имеется форма с ID artform, то должно работать!

Answer (score 1):

## Вернуть форму к исходному состоянию:

- Используя [`<input type="reset">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset):

```html
<form>
  <p>Введите что-нибудь в поля:</p>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input type="reset" value="Очистить форму">
</form>
```

- Либо, используя обычную кнопку, повесив обработчик на неё, который будет вызывать метод [`reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) формы:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('form');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => form.reset());
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <p>Введите что-нибудь в поля:</p>
  <input>
  <input>
  <button type="button" id="button">Очистить</button>
</form>
```

## Очистить все поля формы:

- Получаем все поля формы используя метод [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)
- итерируемся по ним, используя [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- присваиваем атрибуту [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value) поля пустую строку

```js
function clearAllFormInputs() {
  let form = document.getElementById('form');
  let inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (let input of inputs)
    input.value = '';
}

let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', clearAllFormInputs);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input value="текст1">
  <input value="текст2">
  <button id="button">Очистить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Вроде бы автор прямым текстом написал, что в его случае reset не работает

Comment: @andreymal, ну да, но, возможно, это пригодится кому-нибудь другому